# Java and Selenium, Clicking element by xpath using contains

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am having a problem clicking an element using Selenium and Java. Here is what the table looks like.

```
<tr class="even">
<td class="linked-item">
<a title="Imported Gatekeeper" href="/rss-servlet/remotesupport/viewgatekeeper.action?siteId=20">SJHS_OK - Technology Center   -  (CWx Network Connectivity)</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td class="linked-item">
<a title="Imported Gatekeeper" href="/rss-servlet/remotesupport/viewgatekeeper.action?siteId=26">SJHS_OK - Technology Center   -  (CWx Network Connectivity) - Backup</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to select the first element SJHS_OK - Technology Center   -  (CWx Network Connectivity), which is a link to another page. This is only a segment of the code, there is much more than this.

My problem arises when I try to use contains, my xpath looks something like this:
`//*[@title='Imported Gatekeeper'][contains(.,'SJHS_OK - Technology Center   -  (CWx Network Connectivity)')][not(contains(.,'Backup'))]`
Sometimes when I put it into firepath it works and finds the element, sometimes it doesn't. Not sure why it doesn't always work.

my code in Java looks like this:
`String gatekeeper = "SJHS_OK - Technology Center   -  (CWx Network Connectivity)"
DRIVER.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Imported Gatekeeper']"+gatekeeper+"[not(contains(.,'Backup'))]")).click();`

I am doing it this way so that I can easily change the gatekeeper variable and select a different gatekeeper. The gatekeeper will be pulled from an excel sheet.

Any help with what is wrong here would be appreciated, or maybe another way that I can go about finding the element to click it that can be changed by a variable.

Comment: may be introduce a wait or sleep in the program and try

Answer (score 0):

If the xpath sometimes finds and sometimes does not, the problem probably is a missing wait. If the element does not exist or is not visible when you try to click, code will throw an error. Try it:

```
WebElement yourElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@title='Imported Gatekeeper'][contains(.,'SJHS_OK - Technology Center   -  (CWx Network Connectivity)')][not(contains(.,'Backup'))]")));
```

**@Edit**

As wait is not working and code stills sometimes working and sometimes no, when te page is renderized, there is no a constant number of spaces to fills the text. Try this xpath selector:

```
//a[@title='Imported Gatekeeper'][text()[contains(., 'SJHS_OK')]][contains(., 'Technology Center')][contains(., 'CWx')][contains(., 'Network')][contains(., 'Connectivity')][not(contains(.,'Backup'))]
```

Also, try all these selectors in google chrome console when test works and not in chrome console. You can test an xpath using an `$x("your xpath here")`

Comment: I tried the wait, it times out no matter the time that I give it. I feel like there is something wrong with the path, since it works sometimes in firepath and sometimes it doesn't, and I can't really see a difference when it does and doesn't.

Comment: I think the xpath is not the problem. Or a xpath works or not. If sometimes work and sometimes no, there is some external interference

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use xpath for that. If you are using Java8 Try this instead:

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).stream()
    .filter(td -> !td.getText().contains("Backup"))
    .findFirst().get().click();
```

If the element can be found either way, there can be something underneath that, maybe element wasn't loaded completely? 
Can you provide stacktrace when error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I copied the SJHS_OK - Technology Center   -  (CWx Network Connectivity directly out of Xpath then it would work, but if I typed it myself, even if it was exact when compared, it would not work. My conclusion is that it has to do with the spaces. The error would disappear if I cut it down without the spaces.